# Non interactive steam install on linux/debian (how to auto-accept EULA?)

Tags: automation, debian, steam, debconf

I'm trying to install steam with apt non-interactively, but I can't figure out how to auto-accept the EULA during install.

Using the answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1122466/script-auto-accepting-eula-license-agreement) as a guide, I pre-set the required debconf parameters:

```
$ echo steam steam/license note '' | sudo debconf-set-selections
$ echo steam steam/question select "I AGREE" | sudo debconf-set-selections
$ sudo debconf-show steam
* steam/license:
* steam/question: I AGREE
```

I confirmed that these are the right parameters by installing steam manually a=first and checking them with `sudo debconf-show steam`

But when I go to install, get the error:   "Installation terminated: Steam License Agreement was DECLINED."

```
$ sudo apt install steam
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  steam:i386
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 10 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/875 kB of archives.
After this operation, 2,664 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 327614 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../steam_1%3a1.0.0.48-1ubuntu4_i386.deb ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/steam_1%3a1.0.0.48-1ubuntu4_i386.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 30
Installation terminated: Steam License Agreement was DECLINED.
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/steam_1%3a1.0.0.48-1ubuntu4_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How can I get this to work?

Comment: install steamcmd instead of steam. follow the latest docs at https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/SteamCMD#Downloading_SteamCMD

Comment: Does that install the GUI Steam Client or only the CLI Steam client? It sounds like a CLI-only steam

Comment: oops. this is only for the CLI version

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in another thread https://askubuntu.com/a/1017487

The gist that you need to use `debconf-set-selections`

```
echo steam steam/question select "I AGREE" | sudo debconf-set-selections
echo steam steam/license note '' | sudo debconf-set-selections
```